# Does transformer line side voltage varies with backup generator on load side running at from 0 to 100%?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, impedance, high-voltage, generator

We have a transformer of 750 KVA with 5.75% impedance. On the load side we have loads and a back-up emergency generator. This emergency generator is capable of supplying the loads and still export some energy to the utility. Today a senior engineer in a meeting said:

***Going from 0% load to 100% load on this transformer will result in a
5.75% drop in voltage. Going from 0% load to 50% load on this transformer will result in a 2.875% drop in voltage.***

I totally understand this since in this case the backup generator is not running and the voltage supplied to the load has a loss when passing through the transformer winding

However he also said:

***Going from 0% load to 100% generator output (100% of transformer rating would be 750 KVA or approx 750 Amps) will result in a 5.75% increase in voltage.So if the voltage in the plant is approx 620V at 0% load, it will increase to 656V at 750KVA generator output.***

I don't understand this part. The generator is set to synchronize to the grid at whatever voltage it is operating. After this it gradually starts to increase kW output while maintaining the voltage.

1. Why would there be a voltage increase on the load if the generator control loop is keeping it at whatever voltage the grid has?
2. What would happen to the voltage on the line side of the transformer? Isn't there also a loss from the voltage the generator is outputting as it tries to get across the transformer impedance and get to the grid?

Comment: 1.Why is there a 5.75% drop on the load side of the transformer? 2.Once the generator begins supplying the load (and taking load off the transformer) what happens to the voltage on the load side of the transformer (since the transformer has less load)?

Comment: @brhans 1) Transformer impedance 2) When the transformer is unloaded its impedance does not decrease the voltage. But that happens at the exact moment where the generator supplies only what the load requires. As the generator supplies more and starts to export energy, the transformer impedance appears once again, although in this case I think the difference would be noted on the line side